# HP ProCurve & Cisco switches interoperability

Tags: cisco, vlan, switch, hp-procurve

I have a couple of questions regarding Cisco and HP ProCurve interoperability. Here's [a link](http://www.pdfhost.net/index.php?Action=DownloadFile&id=f6cc63dba0d4816e35547555f818ea9c) to pdf with my network topology. Can someone help me with basic VLAN configuration in such topology? Below there are some details of my configuration:

```
# m_management_2
interface FastEthernet0/43
 switchport access vlan 250
 switchport mode access
 spanning-tree port-priority 32
 spanning-tree cost 100

# MTA2-swmgmt1
vlan 1
 name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
 untagged 1-48
 ip address 10.10.249.190 255.255.255.128
 exit

# MTA2-swtr1
vlan 1
 name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
 untagged 1-14,16-48
 no ip address
 no untagged 15
 exit
vlan 100
 name "MTA Mgmt"
 untagged 15
 ip address 10.10.249.188 255.255.255.128
 exit

# MTA2-swtr2
vlan 1
 name "DEFAULT_VLAN"
 untagged 1-14,16-48
 no ip address
 no untagged 15
 exit
vlan 100
 name "MTA Mgmt"
 untagged 15
 ip address 10.10.249.189 255.255.255.128
 exit
```

I don't post MTA2-bcsw[12] configuration, because I wasn's successfull in this one yet. Every time I configure VLANs on MTA2-bcsw[12] Fa0/24 interface on m_management_2 goes down bacause of receiving tagged BPDUs on access port (there are no VLANs configured on MTA2-swmgmt1 because of fact that only 250 VLAN is allowed in this switch. Is it correct?). Can someone provide me some basic configuration for this topology?

Second thing I want to ask is concept of connection from MTA2-swmgmt1 to MTA2-swtr[12] HP switches for the sake of management. How to configure such ports on HP switches (managed switch and manager switch). Is my actual configuration correct?

Comment: Do you have trunks configured on these switches?  You might want to post more of the configs for us to have a better idea on how you have things set up, and what is currently working.  Also, it would probably be useful to see your config for MTA2-bcsw[12] to see what you were trying to do.

Comment: one note - IIRC "trunk" means different things to HP and cisco.  I think cisco calls multi-vlan connection a trunk.  HP's "trunk" is a multi-link connection aka link aggregation (cisco uses the name etherchannel).